# Why it doesn't run the method "run"?

Tags: java, methods

I have this class that it starts executing the method "parametro" but it doesn't run anything else and I can't find out why not..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class Proceso extends Thread{
    
    String variable;
    
    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(variable+" en run");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        /*
        more lines of code
        */
    }
    
    public void parametro(String comando){
        this.variable = comando;
        System.out.println(variable+" en parametro");
    }
    
}
```

So it only prints the command in 'parametro' method, then ends...

Note:
to everybody: I'm sorry for my lack of information
So the missing info is that from the main class I'm calling this in this way:

```
// some code before
        String fichero = args[0];
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String linea = "";
        Proceso hilo = new Proceso();
        
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));
            while((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                hilo.parametro(linea);
            }
// some code after
```

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: I don't know if I answered you or if my answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you answered. The problem is that instantiating a class that inherits from `Thread` is not enough to make it run. You have to use the `start` method to (you guessed it) start it :)

Comment: add-on to @FedericoklezCulloca, just call `hilo.start()` after `hilo.param...(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it possible be because you didn't initialize a thread? Try wrapping the run method in a new thread.

```
new Thread(
    @Override
    public void run() {
        *your code here*
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the run method to do anything, you have to start the thread by initializing an object of the class and call the `start()` method.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. But if I were you I'd remove the speculative part of your answer, now that OP edited the question to include the much needed information.